# What was the original ending supposed to be like?

Tags: ending, miami-vice-2006

The 2006 movie version of [*Miami Vice*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0430357/) ends with a showdown between *Vice*, *Jose Yero* and his Aryan Brotherhood accomplices at a desolate shipyard in Miami. However, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami_Vice_%28film%29#Filming) says that the ending was rewritten after production problems:

> After gunshots were fired on set in the Dominican Republic on October 24, 2005, Foxx packed up and refused to return; this forced Mann to re-write the film's ending, which some crew members characterized as less dramatic than the original.

This awakes my interest in this dropped alternative ending (as it was likely set abroad, I guess it could have involved *Montoya* himself, whose disappearance was a bit unspectacular). But while this was apparently never filmed, its plot seems to be known to the crew at least. So, **is there any secured information how the story of this original ending was to unfold?**

Comment: Such a shame Mann's commentary track for this movie is so booooring (explaining the plot!), whereas he could have talked about far more interesting subjects.

Answer (score 3):

The original ending was supposed to take place in Paraguay. The original report about Jaime Foxx's attitude and the change in endings was from a [Slate article](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/hollywood/2006/07/fleeing_the_scene.html).

> Mann had to rewrite the ending, eliminating a version that was to have been shot in Paraguay

The only other information I could find on the original ending is from an [Entertainment Weekly article](http://www.ew.com/ew/article/0,,1217272_3,00.html).

> The plan had been to shoot for a few days in a local mall and then for three weeks in an abandoned building outside town, where they'd film a climactic gun battle that was said to rival the finale of Heat in scope and ambition.
>
> "There was a list. Two hundred and thirty-six line items of weapons, ammunition, and explosives for that scene," says Donehoo. "And of course, the State Department bureaucracy was not in a big hurry to hand out export permits for a bunch of AK-47s into the area known for its relationship with Hamas and Hezbollah. So that was a trick."